# Comparing keywords in a page or CSV file: PHP ? Bash?

Tags: php, python, bash, logic

I have a series of keywords in an HTML web page - they are comma separated so I could get them to CSV, and would like to know which ones are NOTin another CSV file displayed as an html web page.
How would you do that comparison ? I have ideas for mysql and tables but this is CSV or html sources.
Thanks !

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? It sounds confusing whether you want to compare csv with csv or html. Can you post some examples of mentioned data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, given 2 csv files, a.csv and b.csv, this script will create (or edit if it already exists) a new file out.csv that contains everything in a.csv that's not found in b.csv.

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.website.com/x.csv'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, 'b.csv')


file_a = open('a.csv', 'r')
file_b = open('b.csv', 'r')    
file_out = open('out.csv', 'w')

list_a = [x.strip() for x in file_a.read().split(',')]
list_b = [x.strip() for x in file_b.read().split(',')]    
list_out = list(set(list_a) - set(list_b)) # Reverse if necessary

file_out.write(','.join(list_out))
file_out.close()
```

Comment: Looks interesting. As the 2nd CSV is updated on another site, is there a way it could be called from an absolute URL ? I already have the 1st csv file locally and it will not change.

Comment: Will try with an absolute URL then :)

Comment: Updated it to to download the other site's csv file first.

Comment: @mrt Actually you can avoid the loop by using `list_out = list(set(list_b)-set(list_a))` (get items from `list_b` that do not exist in `list_a`) and you will get the list you need to output into the file.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a list of keywords, you want to do a search and replace (you can use sed) to replace all the commas with carriage returns.  So you will end up with a file containing one keyword on each line.  Do that to both versions of the list.  Then use the "join" command:

```
join -v 1 leftfile rightfile
```

This will report all the entries in leftfile that are not in rightfile.  Don't forget to sort the files first, or join won't work.  There is a bash tool for sorting too (it's called, not surprisingly, "sort").

Answer (score 1):

PHP solution..
Get keywords as strings, convert then in arrays and use array_diff function:

```
<?php
$csv1 = 'a1, a2, a3, a4';
$csv2 = 'a1, a4';

$csv1_arr = explode(',', $csv1);
$csv2_arr = explode(',', $csv2);

$diff = array_diff($csv1_arr, $csv2_arr);
print_r($diff);
```

?>